# Como funciona a função Router do Express

Tags: javascript, express.js, node.js

Para usar um middleware no Express, faço como o código abaixo:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use('/', function(req, res, next) { 
    console.log('Middleware!');
});
```

Porém, percebi que também é possível fazer isso:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var app = express();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('Index!');
});

router.get('/teste', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('Teste!');
});

app.use('/', router);
```

Como a função Router funciona? O que ela faz debaixo dos panos?

Answer (score 1):

express.Router() é um gerenciador/manipulador de rotas do NodeJS. Ela serve para criar rotas de forma modularizada, assim possibilitando criar um arquivo separado de manipulação de rotas.

Por exemplo, crie um diretorio chamado "rotes" e crie um arquivo "indexRotes.js". Dentro deste arquivo você vai utilizar o Router() para criar uma estruturas de rotas que em breve serão exportadas.

**indexRotas.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router() //chamei de router mas poderia ser qualquer outro nome

router.use((req, res, next) => {...})

router.get('/', (req, res) => {...})

router.get('/home', (req, res) => {...})

router.get('/login', (req, res) => {...})
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {...})

//404
router.use((req, res) => {
    res.send('404: Page not found')
})

module.exports = router
```

Repare que usei o **Router()** para criar varias rotas e no final o exportei. Agora no arquivo **apps.js** eu posso importa-lo.

**app.js**

```
//IMPORTS EXTERNAL   
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

//IMPORTS INTERNAL
const routes = require('./rotes/indexRotes') //importando o roteador

//SERVER CONFIG
app.use(...)
app.use(...)
app.listen(...)

//ROUTES
app.use('/', routes)
```

Pronto, agora você tem um arquivo separado que cuida especificamente de suas rotas, com direto a middlewares e muito mais, numa grande aplicação pode conter centenas de rotas, então é mais interessante um roteador modular que cuide apenas disso.

Dica: recomendo você declarar o **next** apenas quando for usa-lo, assim mantem o código mais limpo e sem informações desnecessárias.